Simulating 100k request on jmeter
i want to try simulating 100k request to my API using JMeter, i tried to used the setting like this

but the graph on my cloud run, it's like the request not processed.
this is the JMeter result :

this the chart graph :

or is that something on my JMeter set up that i set wrong?
Thank you for your help!


Well, first of all I don't think you can run 100000 requests at once from one machine because you only have 65535 maximum TCP ports plus operating system and other software consumes internally some of them
Moreover you need to properly tune your operating system TCP/IP parameters as by default only subset of ephemeral ports is available to the user
Also you need to properly tune JMeter, at least follow JMeter Best Practices
It's not very clear what is your desired load pattern, like shoot 100000 users running 1 request at once, gradually increase the load and keep 100000 users online for some time, several spikes, etc.

In order to have 100000 online concurrent users you will definitely need to go for Distributed Testing, the remaining configuration depends on the point 4.

Thank for your answer, actually i want to know how much my server can handle for a request.
and i want to test the concurrently for 50k user request to my server
that's why i tried to simulating the100k.
